# How to make google map tiles tapable in swift

Tags: swift, google-maps, ios9, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm working with google maps sdk in ios9 and I'm currently displaying tile layers over the map with different colors that represent a value. I want to add the ability to tap a tile and display information about the tile such as what the actual value of that tile is. I looked online and the only thing I found was to make transparent markers for each tile and then write a handler for each marker to display the value, but I think there has to be a more efficient way to do this. Can someone lead me in the right direction? Thanks!

```
class MyMapView: UIView{

var myMap: GMSMapView!
var closestPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D!

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("This class does not support NSCoding")
}


init(closestPoint: CLLocationCoordinate2D!){
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)

    self.backgroundColor = UIVariables.blackOpaque

    self.closestPoint = closestPoint

    var camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(AppVariables.location2D!.latitude, longitude: AppVariables.location2D!.longitude, zoom: 6)
    self.myMap = GMSMapView.mapWithFrame(CGRectZero, camera: camera)
    self.myMap.mapType = GoogleMaps.kGMSTypeSatellite

    delay(seconds: 0.5) { () -> () in

        let path = GMSMutablePath()
        path.addCoordinate(self.closestPoint!)
        path.addCoordinate(AppVariables.location2D!)
        let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(path: path)
        self.myMap.moveCamera(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 50.0))

        let layer = MyMapTileLayer()
        layer.map = self.myMap
    }

    self.myMap.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    //self.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, 400)

    self.addSubview(self.myMap)



    let viewsDictionary = ["map": self.myMap]
    let metricDictionary = ["width": self.frame.size.width/2]


    let view_constraint_V1:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[map]-15-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.AlignAllLeading, metrics: metricDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    let view_constraint_H1:Array = NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|-10-[map]-10-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: metricDictionary, views: viewsDictionary)

    self.addConstraints(view_constraint_V1)
    self.addConstraints(view_constraint_H1)
}

func delay(seconds seconds: Double, completion:()->()) {
    let popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64( Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds ))

    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        completion()
    }
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Initialization code
}

}


class MyTileLayer: GMSTileLayer{
var webService = WebService()

override func requestTileForX(x: UInt, y: UInt, zoom: UInt, receiver: GMSTileReceiver!) {

    webService.getTiles(x, y: y, z: zoom, completion: { (result) -> Void in

        receiver.receiveTileWithX(x, y: y, zoom: zoom, image: UIImage(data: result))
    })
}

}
```

Comment: Can you able share your code!, square tiles means? infowindows/Marker

Comment: Updated with code that might be useful, but what I'm asking is pretty generic so my code shouldn't really matter. When I said square tiles, I really just mean google map tile layers

Comment: Tap gesture problem that I faced while using gesture action on google map so I used touchbegan function for my action. Otherwise we would try this: mapView.settings.consumesGesturesInView=true

Comment: Interesting.. I found a function that gives you the coordinate on the map where the user tapped: func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView!, didTapAtCoordinate coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D). Think I could use this. Thanks for the help!

Comment: didTapAtCoordinate func will invoke while tap at goole map.

Comment: Any resolution so far ?